# ASP.NET Core authentication: how to store principal data in a database instead of cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 6 web application which has a user-configurable system for choosing authentication providers (OIDC, Sustainsys SAML2, Google, Microsoft Identity, etc.). Based on the configuration, one or more "providers" may be chosen, with each one having a unique authentication scheme. I am not using ASP.NET Core Identity, as it's a legacy system that I am not ready to retrofit.

I am using "cookie" authentication as the glue, so in my `ConfigureServices` method, I may have something like the following:

```
AuthenticationBuilder authBuilder = services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
       ...
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect(
       "MyOpenIdConnectProvider", // authenticationScheme
       this.ConfigureOidcOptions);
```

My problem is that in some cases, a huge amount of data comes back in the claims from the identity provider. Because of this, I get a correspondingly huge amount of data stored in the `.AspNetCore.Cookies` cookies (in one case, there are 5 chunks of cookies with over 18 kb of data in total).

With this amount of data, I am getting all sorts of things breaking down because there is simply too much header data.

I'm thinking that I can solve this problem by somehow storing all of this claims data in a database, rather than in cookies.

The question is, how can I configure ASP.NET Core to do this? Do I have to write a custom authentication handler which replaces the [CookieAuthenticationHandler](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/Cookies/src/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs)?

For reference, I am triggering authentication by sending returning a `ChallengeResult` for the requested auth scheme. For example:

```
return new ChallengeResult("MyOpenIdConnectProvider", authProps);
```

The `authProps` (`AuthenticationProperties`) contains the redirect URI which specifies the callback path. In the controller action corresponding to the callback, I get the authentication result containing all the claims using something like:

```
AuthenticateResult authRes = authContext.AuthenticateAsync("Cookies").Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to create a custom authentication scheme, this could help:
https://referbruv.com/blog/implementing-custom-authentication-scheme-and-handler-in-aspnet-core-3x/

Also Redis is happy to assist you :)